# How do I remove a role with a discord bot after a certain amount of time? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, roles

> My code is as follows:

```
async run(message, args)
{
    if(message.content.split(" ").length === 3 && message.content.split(" ") 
    [0] == '!suspend' && message.content.split(" ")[1].startsWith("<") && 
    message.content.split(" ")[1].endsWith(">"))
    {
        var nab = message.content.split(" ")[1]; // 2nd item in array when text is split by spaces, (ex. `@user`)
        var nabwoo = message.content.split(" ")[2]; //3rd item in array when the text is split by spaces, (ex. `12h`)
        let role = message.guild.roles.find(r => r.name === "Suspended");
        //nab is the users id
        let member = message.mentions.members.first();
        member.addRole(role);
        message.channel.sendMessage('Done.');
    }
}
```

My code is supposed to apply a role called `'Suspended'` to someone after a message like !`suspend @user blank.` Everything works great, except I'm unsure how to remove a role after a certain amount of time. There is the method `member.removeRole(role)` but how would I do this automatically after a specified amount of time? I want there to be a 3 command input. `!suspend @person timeInHours (with or without units).` As I said, I want it done automatically so a user doesn't have to remove the role with a command. I also want to be able to input other commands (basically suspend other people) while the bot is counting the time until the unsuspension. How would I go about doing this? An idea I have is to perhaps check every minute if it's been > x number of minutes since the suspension.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure as I'm new to this as well, BUT since you delete a message after sometime using `.then(msg => {msg.delete(600)})` I would assume, you could do something similar, like replace the msg.delete(600), with a method to get rid of roles sorry if this wasn't useful I was just suggesting a way you could take this.